Find vector with multiples of integer but not differ much

Let $S$ is  a $n\times m$ matrix with all entries $0,1$. Now for each column there is at most $t$ many $1$'s. Now let we are given a vector $v\in \mathbb{N}^m$. Now find a vector $v'$ where each element of the vector $v'$ is a multiple of $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall j\in[n]$ $$|S(v-v')_j|\leq kt$$ where $S(v-v')_j$ is the $j$th element of that vector.

So what i thought is we first take a vector $v''$ where each element is just the closest multiple of $k$ to $v_j$ forall $j\in [m]$. Then we go over again and take $j$th element of $v''$. It contributes to at most $t$ many positions. So if more than half of them have the constraints we keep it as it was other wise we change. But i cant prove any results. Help me out
